# Package for angle commands

Tags: amsmath, angle

I want to use the command "\angle". I have the "amsmath" package included im my document, and I can use any other math commands, but not this. What I need to do? It requires a different package?

Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) the "extra" symbols in the ams collection are defined separately from `amsmath`.  `\usepackage{amssymb}` is required.  (this question will probably be closed, as the answer can easily be found by the mechanism described in this question: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Comment: I'm new at this! Sorry xD

Comment: no need to be sorry.  everyone here was once new at it.